# Installation of Windows 7 on Acer Laptop

Tags: windows-7

The computer started using the Windows installation disc. Remove the Windows installation disc and restart your computer so that Windows starts normally. Then insert the Windows installation disc and restart the upgrade. (Do not select "Custom (advanced)" to perform an upgrade. "Custom (advanced)" installs a new copy of Windows and deletes your programs and settings.) How do i go about this stage?

Comment: what do you actually want to do?. a clean installation or something other?. if you need a clean installation then go for custom and if you need to do any up gradation then select upgrade.

Comment: I want to do an upgrade installation.

Comment: Is there a way i can go passed that stage other than doing a clean install?

Comment: what is your current OS/version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to only choose one of the options - upgrade or clean install. I recommend a clean install every time as this will erase your hard disk and start from fresh.

If your previously installed OS supports an upgrade to Windows 7 then the upgrade option will retain your files and programs. Obviously this way will retain your user data, but if you have a good backup procedure of your data and don't mind spending *some* time re-installing applications it can make your life a lot easier in the long run... especially if your computer may have malware and other not-so-niceties!

Please read the Microsoft's official documentation on Upgrade vs. Clean install: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749581(v=ws.10).aspx